# Ubuntu will not start with Nvidia drivers installed

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 15.04, thinkpad

When I have the nvidia graphics drivers installed. My computer just gives me the error `Starting Light Display manager... and Deal with any system changes... link was shut down.....`
I have a lenovo thinkpad W540 with a Quadro k2100m.  I am running ubuntu 15.04 and was trying to install the 352.30 drivers.  What can I do to fix this problem?

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Device 221e
 Kernel Driver in use: i915
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Nvidia Corporation GK106GLM [Quadro K2100m] (reva1)
     Subsystem: Lenovo Device 221e
     Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

I installed the drivers from the xorg-edgers ppa.  I installed them with synaptic package manager.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: And how did you install the drivers?

Comment: @Pilot6 There I edited the question

Comment: Attempt #2: how did you install the drivers?

Answer (score 0):

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

I hope this will fix your problem.

Comment: That did not work for me I still get the error.